# ArcMap: Output to XML Including Shape Data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geometry, xml

I need to create a solution for *non-technical* people to export data from an ArcMAP document (.mxd) to XML files. I will need each feature's data to be exported in such a way that the output xml file (or could be an Excel file) contains both spatial and non-spatial attributes.

The only I put I see which has the required data is a Google Earth .kmz file. Now, I have been able to convert the .kmz to .kml using some .NET code but the final .kml file is too unstructured to be parsed by my .NET code.

I have tried xToolsPro and they do directly output to .kml file but that doesn't good either--and costs $250 for the license (the export function will expire after the trial).

So what are my options? Could I program some Python script and create some extension to Arctoolbox?

I am stuck! Can't believe this kind of functionally is not built-in (export to xml including Shape data).

Comment: using ogr2ogr you could automate conversion of all .shp to GML (xml) format without needing your users to do it manually. Then you can parse the GML in .NET

Comment: tomfumb: Interesting. I will check it out. The tool has to be very easy to use--some of the users can be student interns or grad students. Thanks.

Comment: your .NET tool could be a standalone or an ArcMap add-in that calls ogr2ogr and then manages the GML output - very user-friendly. However I think you should update your question with what you ultimately want to achieve. You mention parsing the XML for... something. If you describe your end-goal you might find a tool / approach that negates some of the steps

Comment: Tomfumb: Thanks again. But the .NET application will be an ASP.NET application which will parse either xml or kml file and then post to a database. My question is about how to get that file--the only solution I have found is the one at: http://www.xtoolspro.com/tools.asp ; it is the only one which outputs from mxd in a structured .kml file which my .NET application is parsing fine.

Answer (score 1):

ESRI has an standard xml format to export both the data and the schema of data.

**In ArcCatalg (Catalog window of Arcmap):**

1- As arcgis cannot export shapefile directly to XML workspace first import your shapefile into a geodatabase featureclass.

2- right-click the featureCLass > Export> XML Workspace Document

[image]

in the opened window there are two combo boxes. select like this snapshot:

[image]

I hope it helps.

**Update:**
kmz is the compression format for kml file (like zip format). You need to just extract the kmz to kml using winrar or winzip. Furthermore ArcGIS has a tool to convert a layer including shapefile layer to KMZ (no extra cost!). The Geoprocessing tool name  is "Layer to KML".

Comment: Thanks. But we have the data in .mxd which is fed by .shape files. So where exactly I would see this option?

Comment: I updated the answer. in arcmap click the catalog botton to open catalog windows and then locate your shapefile and follow my answer.

Comment: Farid: Thanks. But these are non-technical people. There will be literally dozens, if not over a hundred buildings, and most buildings will have 'Room Data' and 'Floor Plans' (and possibly other) MXDs--so two MXD's per building. So far, other than xToolsPro, nothing is looking promising. I really appreciate your help though!

Comment: Meengla, What I suggested in my answer is just some simple steps. a user can even batch import shapefiles into a geodatabase and then export the whole geodatabase to xml workspace with data.

Comment: I read your question again, why do you write code to convert kmz to kml?! please See the update answer.

Comment: Farid, I appreciate the new help. Some of these users will probably be student interns or grad students. There is a high turn-over--it is a university. So I want to make it as simple as possible: Design the map in ArcMAP, export via xProtools to a .kml file, then upload via web page.

Comment: I looked into kmz-to-kml because ArcMAP outputs to kmz and that would be a 'free' solutio--not requiring xProtools. But the .NET script had to parse as .kml and thus kmz-to-kml. Problem is that kml produced that way is not structured the way xProtool's kml output is.